Existence of optimal entropic weights for empirical modeling
Let $\mathcal{X} = [0,1]^n$ be the input space and $\mathcal{Y} = \{1, ..., n_c\}$ be a discrete output space. Let $D = \{(x_i, y_i)\}_{i=1}^N \subset \mathcal{X} \times \mathcal{Y}$ be a training dataset.
A feature subspace $S$ is defined as a subset of input features, indexed by a binary string $s \in \{0, 1\}^n$. Let $\mathcal{S} = \{S_1, ..., S_M\}$ be a finite set of feature subspaces.
For each subspace $S$, a quantization function $Q_S: [0,1]^{|S|} \to \{1, ..., m_S\}$ partitions the projection of $\mathcal{X}$ onto $S$ into $m_S$ cells.
The local entropy of cell $C_{iS}$ in subspace $S$ is:
$$E_{iS} = -\frac{1}{\ln m_S} \sum_{k=1}^{n_c} p(k|C_{iS}) \ln p(k|C_{iS})$$
where
$$p(k|C_{iS}) = \frac{|\{(x,y) \in D: y=k \land Q_S(x|_S) = i\}|}{|\{ (x,y) \in D: Q_S(x|_S) = i \}|}$$
The local entropic weight is $W_{iS} = 1 - E_{iS}$.
The global entropic weight $W_{cS}$ for output category $c$ in subspace $S$ is the average local entropic weight over cells with at least one data point of category $c$:
$$W_{cS} = \frac{\sum_{i: p(c|C_{iS}) > 0} W_{iS}}{|\{i: p(c|C_{iS}) > 0\}|}$$
Let $\mathcal{W}$ be the set of all functions $W: \{1, ..., m_S\} \times \mathcal{S} \times \mathcal{Y} \to [0,1]$.
The predicted probability for category $c$ given input $x$ and weighting function $W$ is:
$$P_W(c|x) = \frac{1}{M} \sum_{j=1}^M W(Q_{S_j}(x|_{S_j}), S_j, c)$$
The empirical risk on the training data $D$ for a weighting function $W$ is:
$$R(W) = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{(x,y) \in D} \mathbb{I}[y \neq \arg\max_c P_W(c|x)]$$
where $\mathbb{I}$ is the indicator function.
Question:
Does there exist a weighting function $W^* \in \mathcal{W}$ that minimizes the empirical risk, i.e., $R(W^*) = \inf_{W \in \mathcal{W}} R(W)$?
